# Angular - ngModel not updating until I click on textarea

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a google-chrome popup with a text box in it. When the user types into the textbox, the text is saved into chrome local storage. When the popup is closed and then reopened, the text box is supposed to autofill with the last text that was saved. It is working perfectly, except when I close and open the popup, the text field appears to be empty and does not autofill until I click on the text field. I know that the value is changed right when the popup opens because it is logging to the console, I just can't see the change until after I click. Any Idea what I am doing wrong?

app.componenet.html

```
<div>

  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Input</mat-label>
    <textarea matInput [(ngModel)]='myText' (ngModelChange)="saveChanges()"></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>

</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  ngOnInit() {this.restore()};

  title = 'dataStoreTest';
  myText = '';

  saveChanges() {
    chrome.storage.local.set({storedText: this.myText});
    console.log('save');
  }

  restore(){
    let self = this;
    chrome.storage.local.get( ['storedText'], function(result){
      self.myText = result.storedText;
      console.log(result.storedText +' Was restored');
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: can u see output `console.log(result.storedText +' Was restored');`

Comment: and why not using `localStorage` instead

Comment: Yes, It logs out fine. AND it logs the moment that I re-open the popup, not when I click on it. This makes me think that the myText Item is getting updated when I want, it's just not showing up in the actual text box.

Comment: Also, I'm brand new to chrome storage. what is the difference between chrome.storage.local, and chrome.localStorage?

Comment: no i mean, in browser we use localStorage, not `chrome.storage.local` or `chrome.localStorage`. this wont be available on other browser like IE, safari

Comment: Ok, I looked into localStorage some more and you are right, it makes WAY more sense to use that instead. AND, when I switched over to using localStorage, the weird bug fixed itself. I think that maybe because chrome.local.storage.get uses a callback function to get the data it was somehow messing with the textarea update. Anyway, that solved it. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not sure why this was happening, but it was resolved by instead using localStorage and NOT chrome.storage.local-

the fixed code -

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  ngOnInit() {this.restore()};

  title = 'dataStoreTest';
  myText = '';

  saveChanges() {
    localStorage.setItem('storedText', this.myText);
    console.log('save');
  }

  restore(){
      this.myText = localStorage.getItem('storedText');
      console.log(localStorage.getItem('storedText') +' Was restored');
  }

}
```

Comment: I think that callback function of the chrome.storage.local.get method runs **outside of angular zone**, so inside that callback function you either have to use ngZone.run method or trigger change detection manually by injecting ChangeDetectorRef and calling markForCheck method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a name to your control. Try this and let me know if this works for you.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Input</mat-label>
  <textarea
    matInput
    name="myText"
    [(ngModel)]="myText"
    (ngModelChange)="saveChanges()">
  </textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```